# jQuery Ajax Unauthorized 401 Error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, google-reader

I have this code:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$ck = time();
$read = new GoogleReaderAPI( $username, $password );
$token = $read->getToken();

echo "RSS Feed: <input type='text' name='rss_feed' /> <br /> ";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$token' id='token' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$ck' id='ck' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$username' id='username' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$password' id='password' />";
echo '<input type="button" value="Submit" id="click"/>';
echo "<div id='result'></div>";
?>
<script>
jQuery("#click").click(function(){
    var quickadd = escape( jQuery("input[name=rss_feed]").val() );
    var T = escape( jQuery("#token").val() );
    var ck = escape( jQuery("#ck").val() );
    var params = "quickadd="+quickadd+"&T="+T;

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/quickadd?ck="+ck+"&client=scroll",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error when using ajax but when I try to use an ordinary POST method (non-ajax), then I am able to see the output.

 This is an exmaple ouput that i'm seeing when using an ordinary POST

```
{"query":"http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunchIT","numResults":1,"streamId":"feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunchIT"}
```

By the way i'm integrating the google reader account in my application that is why i'm calling that one in the ajax-url.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/quickadd?ck="+ck+"&client=scroll",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                 xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password) //May need to use "Authorization" instead
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/quickadd?ck=1326443814&client=scroll"

Comment: @ElsonSolano replace Authentication to Authorization

Comment: I think 'beforeSend': should be beforeSend:,
@Ramil Amr: I'll change that one.

Comment: hold on, i'm gettinga  weird error: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]  

},

Comment: I'm getting this error in my google chrome console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/quickadd?ck=1326503388&client=scroll. Origin http://my-domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: its seems that cross-domain ajax is not allowed. Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin